# Python3 - inheritance exceptions

Tags: python, exception, inheritance, python-3.x

I've create little class for parsing websites.

There's URLError exception:

```
def visit(self, url, referer=None, data=None):

    (...)

    # Return BeautifulSoup instance.
    try:
        return BeautifulSoup(self.opener.open(self.request))
    # URLError.
    except urllib.error.URLError as error:
        return error
```

Everything works okay. But I'm in need to create a wrapper of this function.

```
def get_links(self, *args, **kwargs):

    # Get links with BeautifulSoup.
    self.links = self.visit(*args, **kwargs).find_all('a')
```

Get_links function also works well until there is URLError (403, 404, whatever...). How can I solve this problem? Is there something as inheritance exceptions?

Comment: What's the error that you're getting?

Comment: E.g. when 404: it prints error reason, but after reason: AttributeError: 'HTTPError' object has no attribute 'find_all'. There is simply no content for the search.

Comment: That's quite allright. Your `visit()` function catches exception and returns a `URLError` object, where you try to call `find_all()` on, which is doesn't have.

Comment: What do you want to happen when there is an error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `visit()` function catches exception and returns you a `URLError` object, on which you're calling `find_all()`, which it doesn't have.

Something in lines of:

```
self.links = self.visit(*args, **kwargs)
if not isinstance(self.links, urllib.error.URLError):
    self.links = self.links.find_all('a')
else:
    # Do something with an HTTP Error
```

Should give you an idea of a flow. You can't catch that exception in your outer `get_links()` because it's already caught by `visit()` and is simply returned.

If you want to catch it in `get_links()`, change

```
return error
```

to

```
raise error
```

in your `visit()` method, although then you'll be throwing the exception you just caught again, I'm not sure whether this is the behavior you want.